variation of convergence of ergodic averages
I am currently stuck on proving the following:

If $\mathbb{X}=(X,\mathfrak{B},\mu,T)$ is weak mixing system then for every $f\in{C(X)}, \alpha\in \mathbb{T}$ there is a set of full measure $X'\subseteq X$ so that for every $x\in{X'}, \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1}e^{2\pi i n^{2}\alpha}f(T^{n}x)$ converges.

The angle I have been working on is through the system $\mathbb{T}$ with the transformation $(y,z)\mapsto (y+\alpha,z+2y+\alpha)$: using the pointwise ergodic theorem, I defined the set to be $E=\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} E_n$, where each $E_n$ is a set of full measure so that for some $y_n\in [0,\frac{1}{n}],\forall x\in E_n,\  \frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{m=0}^{N-1}e^{2\pi i m^{2}\alpha}f(T^{m}x)e^{4\pi i my_n}$ converges. I thought I was supposed to show using limits that this implies the desired limit exists for all $x\in E$, but I'm having a hard time with it - and also kind of suspicious of the fact I hadn't really used the fact the system is weak mixing (although it might just have something to do with a later question, but still.)
I would appreciate any hints or general tips on how to deal with these kinds of questions.
PS: If necessary, it is okay to assume that we are working in a compact metric space. I have been working under this assumption.

Are you really considering an arbitrary $T$? Or should it relate to the fractional parts of the second degree polynomial?

@JohnB I fixed it - T is weak-mixing rather than ergodic. Other than that T is arbitrary.

It is a result of Emmanuel Lesigne from 1993: "Spectre quasi-discret et theoreme ergodique de Wiener-Wintner pour les polynom".  It's called the polynomial extension of the Wiener-Wintner Ergodic Theorem.  I'm unable to access the article, but there is reference here to the result: https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/webfm_send/289 by Tanja Eisner.  I suspect there is an easier proof when $T$ is weak mixing that relies on the fact that weak mixing systems are disjoint from rotations.  That seems to be where you are headed.  To apply the ergodic theorem to a product of two systems: $TxS$ where $S$ is a rotation, it is necessary that $T$ be weak mixing.  However, this applies if $S$ is an ergodic rotation which is not stated here.  However, the Wiener-Wintner ET applies to all $\alpha$.  The proof for $n^2$ uses the van der Corput trick.  I tried typing this into the comments, but ran out of space.  I hope this helps!
